# Somar valores em jquery vindo dos campo input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde!

Tenho o seguinte form,

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_rifa" name="id_rifa" value="qaa">
<input type="hidden" id="id_usuario" name="id_usuario" value="1h0p">
<input type="hidden" id="numeros_bilhetes" name="numeros_bilhetes" value="031,047,048">
<input type="hidden" id="valor_bilhete" name="valor_bilhete" value="154">
<span class="v_total">77</span>
<button type="submit" class="finalizar-btn">Participar</button>
</form>
```

Tenho o seguinte li com os dados

```
<li><a class='ativado btn_compra_rifa' data-valor='$valor_rifa' href='JavaScript:void(0);'><i>$i</i></a></li>
```

Meu jquery

```
$('.btn_compra_rifa').click(function() {

 if ($(this).hasClass('desativado')) {
        $(this).removeClass('desativado').addClass('selecionado');

                var valor_rifa = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-valor"));
                var resultado = $(".v_total").html()

                  $('input[name=valor_bilhete]').val(valor_rifa);


      var bilhete_soma = $('#valor_bilhete').val() + valor_rifa;

$('input[name=valor_bilhete]').val(valor_rifa);

alert(bilhete_soma);
```

Ele não soma os valores, e quando soma ele duplica de uma vez só.. oque estou fazendo de errado?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele tinha que somar 77+77= 154

> **A logica é que a pessoa possa escolher varios numeros, eos valores**
> **irem somando**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você pega um valor de um ***input***, ele é armazenado em uma string. Acredito que o Javascript esteja ***concatenando*** as strings ao invés de ***somar***. Se for este o caso, tente algo como:

```
var bilhete_soma = parseInt($('#valor_bilhete').val()) + parseInt(valor_rifa);
```

*Espero ter ajudado*

Comment: obrigado funcionou